# Python df.plot: How to have x-axis start from the first row of the dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 12 rows, 2 columns (Month and y value). I used numpy.roll so the first row in the dataframe is June. In other words:

[image: Dataframe]

When I plot this dataframe as a bar graph, I get what I want, where the x-axis starts from '6' and ends at '5':

```
monthlyAvg.plot(x='Month', y='NDVI',kind = 'bar',ylim = (0.45,0.65))
```

[image: Bar graph]

However, if I change the kind to a line graph, the x-axis starts at 1 and there's a long line stretching across the chart from 1 to 12 :

[image: Line graph]

How can I change the axis so that it starts at 6, like the bar graph?

Comment: are you sure about it? for bar chart x-axis can be of any name, so it started with the way the sequence of data was(i.e 6,.12,1,3,4,5), for line chart its more like a time series, so 1 should come before 6, so it sorted months so it starts from 1 to 12. i hope this make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because a bar plot treats the x-axis values as categorical variables and leaves them in the order they were entered, whereas a line plot treats the x-axis values as numerical and orders them accordingly.

To get the output you desire with a line graph, you have to convert the x-axis month numbers to strings so that they can be treated as categorical variables.  Here is how:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
monthlyAvg = pd.DataFrame({'Month':[6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5], 'NDVI':[0.59,0.56,0.53,0.54,0.55,0.56,0.55,0.59,0.59,0.57,0.59,0.60]})

plt.plot(monthlyAvg['Month'].astype('str'), monthlyAvg['NDVI'])
plt.ylim(0.45,0.65)
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('NDVI')
plt.show()
```

[image]